# DROP all columns from an existing SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I need to drop all columns in an existing table in SQL Server. It is possible to delete columns by specifying each column name. I want to delete every column without specifying column name. I am looking for something like

```
ALTER TABLE tblUser DROP COLUMN *;
```

Is there any known way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you just want to drop the whole table, use `DROP TABLE tablename`

Comment: drop that table and create new

Comment: Without columns, tables are only a name. If you are dropping all the columns, you may consider dropping the whole table with `DROP TABLE tablename`

Comment: Specify all the column names to remove.. this can be done programmatically with “dynamic SQL”, including generation from an external language. Deleting the table itself has slightly different connotations.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server even allows tables without columns.

Comment: @STaefi and it would also be a rowcount as in this postgres example. https://rextester.com/XLU33952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question literally, no you can't. If you try to remove the last column, SQL Server will throw the following error:

> Msg 4923, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>
> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because 'Id' is the only data column in table 'NoColumns'. **A table must have at least one data column.**

As such, if you actually want to solve your problem, whatever it is, it would be best to voice the initial problem and not the solution you decided to pursue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead remove all the columns, you could drop the table

```
DROP TABLE TABLENAME
```

Or You can mention all the column names in Alter query

```
ALETR TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN Column1, Column2, Column3....ColumnN
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the comments, 
In my case the columns are dynamic and I have to do another insert with different number of columns  right after dropping the first set of columns to the same table.
I tried dropping the table and inserting it, but it throws errors related to batch, my problem here is I need to be stay in same batch also, so a GO statement also not useful. Is there any way we stay in same batch and do a 
drop table tblUser;
INSERT INTO tblUser 
select * from anotherTable

Comment: @NewDeveloper Then do first add all the columns and remove all old columns using `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO #result FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= N'tablename' AND COLUMN_NAME != 'Guid' -- or id
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @colNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @colNames += '['+ r.COLUMN_NAME + ']' +',' from #result r;
SET @colNames = LEFT(@colNames,LEN(@colNames)-1)
DROP TABLE #result;
SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN ' + @colNames;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```